# How do I REGEXP search based on hex codes in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

`SELECT title FROM tags WHERE title REGEXP '[\x20]'` returns all things with x, 2, or 0;
`SELECT title FROM tags WHERE title REGEXP '\x20'` returns all things with literally x20

My actual use-case is that I want to search for any tags that may have accidentally gotten control characters in.

Comment: Any really. I only want "legitimate" characters in there. I'm guessing from 00 to 1F in that top chart, for a start http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT title FROM tags WHERE title REGEXP CONCAT('[',CHAR(1),'-',CHAR(31),']')
```

Note that these are decimal character values, not hex.  I also couldn't figure out a way to get it to find NULL bytes (`\x00`) as well.

Here is an alternative that uses hex literals:

```
SELECT title FROM tags WHERE title REGEXP CONCAT('[', x'01', '-', x'1F', ']')
```

Comment: Yeah it definitely explodes on 00. I don't even understand how your answer works with an x outside of quotes and using CONCAT. Can you explain what it's doing to achieve that answer?

Comment: If MySQL supported `\x` escapes this would construct the string `'[\x01-\x1F]'`.  In regex that would be a character class that matches all characters where the character code is between 1 and 1F (inclusive).  `CONCAT` concatenates strings, so `CONCAT('hello', 'world')` would be 'helloworld'.  You can read about hex literals [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-literal.html).

Comment: Note that you can search for a single XML character by hex code with the following query: `SELECT title FROM tags WHERE title REGEXP x'01'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do it in mysql shell which removes backslashes on their own. The following worked for me:

```
select id, data regexp '\\x1F\\x8B\\x08' from ...;
```